# react bootstrap button not showing

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

`I have used the react bootstrap buttons, but the buttons are not displaying. Other components of react bootstrap are displaying but buttons are not displaying.

I have imported buttons as
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

when I use button as
 variant="primary">Submit

There is a blank page when I have used only buttons

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include your code to reproduce the error that you got.

But also please make sure that you dont have any typo there, and according to the documentation, [docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/buttons/)

> `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'`

and then use it

> `<Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>`